# File based backup in Synology NAS

Tags: backup, nas, synology, synology-diskstation

I've a Synology NAS with two HDD in it. One main HDD and one for the backup of the main.

I want to backup a folder from the main HDD to the backup HDD. Using the HyperBackup App (or package) it copy some data - but HyperBackup is packing the files into chunks or something like that. Thus, I can use the backuped data with HyperBackup only.

What I'm looking for is an app (or package or other solution) to copy (weekly, daily) some data of the main HDD to the backup HDD maintaining the files and folder structure. So that I can use the backup HDD without the NAS later in some case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy files and folders with original structure that can be used directly, file sync may be the better way. 3rd party tool like Aomei free version allowing you to sync files with original format, and set up a schedule to run it automatically. You can refer to the example of [NAS to NAS sync](https://www.ubackup.com/synchronization/nas-to-nas-sync-4125.html).